MS Access Split a Database to External URL
I'm trying to use the split database tool in Microsoft Access and split my database into a front end and back end.  Is there any way to store the back end on an external URL or fake an internal URL as a file path?  When splitting I am prompted for the back end location, Windows asks for a file name on a local area network. Is there a way to share a folder on remote machines using a file path and not a host ip address?  I am connected to a VPN but my company normally shares files with OneDrive, which is not recommended to be used with Access.

I would be very surprised if the tooling had some way to make use of a URL instead of a file path.  And at the very least that server is going to need to be more than a simple HTTP server to allow MS Access to write to a file.  Overall it sounds like you're just asking how to share a folder over a network in Windows?  (Which is probably more on-topic elsewhere, but probably also searchable online.)

Are you talking about the MSAccess+sharepoint combo? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/build-and-publish-an-access-database-to-sharepoint-e68bf007-410c-43b2-bf21-322ddbcf5411

@tgolisch No I'm not using Sharepoint because I made multivalue fields in my database.  Sharepoint can't use them.

sharePoint tables support multi-value fields. You can't use a web based URL, since Access requires a file based back end, or a SharePoint one (or a sql server one). However, in "file mode", then no, "one drive", "sky drive" and any other web based file sharing system can't be used. Access needs read/write ability to PARTS of the file, and none of these systems allow that (they work with word, excel etc. since they are WHOLE file based, but for reasons of performance, Access requires a VALID windows networking file share).

You can host a MS Access back-end database on a remote fileshare as long as you map a local drive letter to the backend file (path). The drive mapping must have read/write permissions.
You can manage the remote location in MS Access via the "External Data" tab and the Linked Table Manager.
MS docs for more info
